# Unable to pass a parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, parameters

Okay. For the iLab my class and I are doing this week, we are working with GUIs. The second program we must design is a guessing game. The program is supposed to randomly generate a number, 0 through 100, and pass that number on to be used later. Here is the code I already have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Guessing_game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        int target();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Random r = new Random();
            int target = r.Next(0, 100);
        }

        private void btnEvaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtGuess.Text == target)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Mind you, the "btnEvaluate_Click" area is not done. This is because the variable "Target" that should be accessible by the program is unable to be read later on.

After reading through some of the comments, I was able to tweak the code so I get one more error: "Field 'Guessing_game.Form1.target' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0" IF anyone is going to try and replicate this, I can tell you exactly how to write it. The GUI should have a label, a text box, and a button. The button needs to get the value given to "target" so it can check the user's guess against target's value. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, if it helps.

Comment: Promote `target` variable to an instance variable (a field of `Form1` class).

Comment: I teach C# at a UK university, and this is something that my first year students almost unanimously suffer from. I call it "Bracket blindness"

Comment: You didn't read the answers properly :) Notice you're creating a *new* `target` variable by adding `int` in front of it. Don't do this, because you want to use the `target` variable you created *outside* the constructor. It should be `target = r.Next(0,100);` and it should also be `int target;`, not `int target();`.

Comment: Right. Just tried that, but I am still getting an error: "Field 'Guessing_game.Form1.target' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0"

Answer (score 4):

Try this, You need to declare `target` public

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int target = r.Next(0, 100);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEvaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtGuess.Text == target)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried that just now. The new error was "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property "Guessing_game.Form1.r'"

Comment: Apply the static keyword on the Random r.

static Random r = new Random();

Comment: If I try that, it will tell me that static is not valid for the item.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `int target` outside of the `public Form()`. Inside your event, change `target` to `target.ToString()`.

Comment: Just tried that. I got this error: "A local variable named 'target' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'target' which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: You must have a different variable, which has the name of target also.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses `{}` define a scope. You've declared the `target` variable within the scope of the constructor (`Form1`). Therefore, in order to make it accessible throughout the class, you can make it a class level variable. For example

```
int target;
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Random r = new Random();
   target = r.Next(0, 100);
}
```

(Although if you plan to use the `Random` object again, you'd want to make that a class level variable as well). Also, you're trying to compare an `int` to a string. It should be

```
if (txtGuess.Text == target.ToString())
{

}
```

Comment: Okay. I tried that, but I got one final error. "Field 'Guessing_game.Form1.target' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0"

Comment: Did you remove the `target = r.Next(0, 100);` line from the constructor? That would case that warning.

Comment: From what my professor told me, I cannot remove the "target = r.Next(0,100);" line. That is what is declaring target to have a random number. Or should that part be with the target outside the constructor?

Comment: No no, I meant that you should keep the line :). I can't see why you're getting that error if that line is still there.

Comment: Well, what needs to be figured out is that the variable of target needs to have whatever random number is created, sent out for the button to use when it is clicked on. That way, the button will be able to check if the user's guess is equal to the random number. Know of any way I can pass the random number out so it can be accessed?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're getting so there must be something else going on that you haven't shown. Try creating a new WinForm project and just adding the above to see if the same error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `target` is local to the constructor and therefore can't be seen anywhere else. Make `target` a field in `Form1` instead. Because this is homework, I'll let you try that out on your own; let us know if you're still stumped.